# How to fetch a particular string using a sed command

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have an input string like below:

```
   VAL:1|b:2|c:3|VAL:<har:919876543210@abc.com>; tag=vy6r5BpcvQ|VAl:1234|name:mnp|VAL:91987654321
```

Like this, there are more than 1000 rows.

I want to fetch the value of the first parameter, i.e., the `a` field and `d` field, but for the `d` field I want only `har:919876543210@abc.com`.

I tried like this:

`cat $filename | grep -v Orig |sed -e 's/['a:','d:']//g' |awk -F'|' -v OFS=',' '{print $1 "," $4}' >> $NGW_DATA_FILE`

The output I got is below:

```
1,<har919876543210@abc.com>; tag=vy6r5BpcvQ
```

I want it like this,

```
1,har:919876543210@abc.com
```

Where did I make the mistake and how do I solve it?

Comment: If you are using Awk anyway, do all of this processing in Awk.

Comment: sometime I may receive value in a same field name like val:  , instead of a and d, then how can I fetch its values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's change of Input_file and OP's comments, adding following now.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS="|"; OFS="," }
{
  sub(/[^:]*:/,"",$1)
  gsub(/^[^<]*|; .*/,"",$4)
  gsub(/^<|>$/,"",$4)
  print $1,$4
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

With shown samples, could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="|"
  OFS=","
}
{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    split($i,arr,":")
    if(arr[1]=="a" || arr[1]=="d"){
      gsub(/^[^:]*:|; .*/,"",$i)
      gsub(/^<|>$/,"",$i)
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$i
    }
  }
  print val
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                               ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS="|"                             ##Setting FS as pipe here.
  OFS=","                            ##Setting OFS as comma here.
}
{
  val=""                             ##Nullify val here(to avoid conflicts of its value later).
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                ##Traversing through all fields here
    split($i,arr,":")                ##Splitting current field into arr with delimiter by :
    if(arr[1]=="a" || arr[1]=="d"){  ##Checking condition if first element of arr is either a OR d
      gsub(/^[^:]*:|; .*/,"",$i)     ##Globally substituting from starting till 1st occurrence of colon OR from semi colon to everything with NULL in $i.
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$i         ##Creating variable val which has current field value and keep adding in it.
    }
  }
  print val                          ##printing val here.
}
' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for the answer it works for the case, I have one doubt what if instead of A and D, I have got in the same field name like both the values are present in D:1|D:<har:919876543210@abc.com>; tag=vy6r5BpcvQ like this then what I have to alter , as the file may contain huge data

Comment: @mark, sorry but this is not clear, please do give more clear example on this one.

Comment: ok, if the case is like this input : -- a:1|b:2|c:3|a:<har:919876543210@abc.com>; tag=vy6r5BpcvQ| if the key is 'a' for both the first and 4 th entry

Comment: @mark, ok so what will be the condition then to print these values then? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: I will update my question i will add the whole set of data I receive

Comment: @mark, So you always want to print 1st column OR its a `VAL` with a single digit you want to print? kindly confirm once.

Comment: As you can see in my sample input there are multiple fields with the name VAL as key, I wanted to get its value present in first position and 4th position and ignore the rest, i.e   
1,<har:919876543210@abc.com> , 1 is the value from first VAL key and second one is the value from VAL present in 4th position, there are many places where VAL is present I want to ignore that

Comment: @mark, Please check my EDIT answer once and let me know if that works for you?

Comment: Yes it worked, I have made small change gsub(/^[^<]*|; .*/,"",$1)
  sub(/[^:]*:/,"",$4) it worked with this one also, Thank you sir

Answer (score 4):

You may also try this [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) script:

```sh
cat file

VAL:1|b:2|c:3|VAL:<har:919876543210@abc.com>; tag=vy6r5BpcvQ|VAl:1234|name:mnp|VAL:91987654321

awk -F '[|;]' '{
   s=""
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i ~ /^VAL:/) {
         gsub(/^[^:]+:|[<>]*/, "", $i)
         s = (s == "" ? "" : s "," ) $i
      }
   print s
}' file

1,har:919876543210@abc.com
```

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for the solution, here accessing the a and d fields and do the filtering, I have one doubt what if instead of 2 different fields a and d , the input changed to a:1|b:2|c:3|a:<har:919876543210@abc.com>; tag=vy6r5BpcvQ like this then how to filter it, as there maybe multiple fields whose name start with same field like d

Comment: @mark wrt `I have one doubt ...` - what you have is a "question", not a "doubt". A doubt means you don't believe something you've been told, a question just means you'd like information about something. It's a common mistake in the English spoken  in India, see [can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question). No big deal of course, just thought you'd like to know.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same thing with `sed` rather easily using Extended Regex, two capture groups and two back-references, e.g.

```
sed -E 's/^[^:]*:(\w+)[^<]*[<]([^>]+).*$/\1,\2/'
```

**Explanation**

- `'s/find/replace/'` standard substitution, where the `find` is;
- `^[^:]*:` from the beginning skip through the first `':'`, then
- `(\w+)` capture one or more word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), then
- `[^<]*[<]` consume zero or more characters not a `'<'`, then the `'<'`, then
- `([^>]+)` capture everything not a `'>'`, and
- `.*$` discard all remaining chars in line, then the `replace` is
- `\1,\2` reinsert the captured groups separated by a comma.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo 'a:1|b:2|c:3|d:<har:919876543210@abc.com>; tag=vy6r5BpcvQ|' | 
sed -E 's/^[^:]*:(\w+)[^<]*[<]([^>]+).*$/\1,\2/'
1,har:919876543210@abc.com
```